# PHP: 500 internal server error page and "could not execute script" in log

Tags: php

I'm working on a website based on static and php pages.

With html pages everything works fine but every time I try to display a PHP page I receive a "500 server internal error" and this message in the log:

> SoftException in Application.cpp:604: Could not execute script "/path/file.php", referer "/path/"

I'm not a php expert, I've tried to:

- put and display a blank php file in different paths.
- change permissions on php files (now they all have a 755 permission)
- look for something wrong in the .htaccess file (but it was blank).

...the error is still there, do you have any suggestion?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you on Hostgator? If so contact their support, they should be able to help you. This must not be overall related to the PHP script but can have other reasons in your hosting configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately the customer is on an host that offers only paid support...

Comment: And the problem is your customer does not want to pay for support? *"SoftException in Application.cpp"* -- normally points to libapache2-mod-suphp - maybe the hoster at least offers configuration instructions and requirements for PHP scripts so you have something you can compare your configuration against?

Comment: You have got it right. However as you have suggested I'm looking for that configuration instructions and requirements... I'm crossing my fingers. I'll let you know, thank you!

Comment: _And the problem is your customer does not want to pay for support?_ This seems to be the rule, rather than the exception these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the customer has decided to pay for extra support. 
The provider told the files had wrong permissions. 
I don't think it was so because, as I've told you, it was the first thing that I've try to change.
However everything is working fine now.

Thank you :)

Comment: Please,  I did all that stuff but with no luck!!